# How can I automate add solution and prioritize supplier for all my components in Altium ActiveBOM?

Tags: altium, bom

I am trying to learn Altium. I have made a schematic with about 70 components and turned that into a PCB. Now I would like to order the parts and want to create a BOM with supplier info so I can order easily all the parts.

I created an ActiveBOM and I notice almost all components donnot have a supplier connected to it.

If I hit Add Solution -> Create/Edit Manufacturer Links -> Add... -> Ok -> Ok, then the supplier will be added. I haven't really made any selections, and in the end Altium chooses a supplier for me among the available ones.

I have two questions.

1. Can't I automate this process so Altium adds a solution and selects a supplier automatically for all my components?
2. Can I set a priority for the different suppliers, so my most preferred supplier is always selected first, when available?

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Comment: It says the forum is unavailable